# Alation APIs for getting column level metadata

Tags: alation

How can I get column level metadata in Alation? I was able to do it for datasource and schema level using Alation APIs but I facing difficulties in getting to the column level. Please help me on this.

Comment: Found the answer

Answer (score 0):

got it.. It's given in their documentation for API under data source browsing.. the link for the same is

https://customerportal.alationdata.com/docs/MetadataGETAPI/index.html